# How to convert given text to array with given key in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a simple OCR app that read an information from a card and succeeded convert the image to text. Here the sample of converted text

> Name :Hulk Color + Green Type Hero

> Name :Venom Color :Black Type Anti Hero

We can see that sometimes colon converted to + or another symbol, the point is how to convert that string to an object with predefined key (in our case is name, color, and type) what is the best approach to do that?

Comment: Show your best attempt, and explain how it fails, and what you expect instead. SO is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: There are too many variables here, but basically you can split by "Color" and you will have 2 elements in your array, fist will be name where you can remove Name and any non alphanumeric characters and you will have first element as the name, and second element will be your color, where you also will have to strip all non alphanumeric chars.

Comment: @Gabriel can you show me an example so i can get small hint what i supposed to do next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, i assumed your output has multiple lines and the names or colors doesn't include non alphanumeric characters, if they do you will have to exclude them from the regex.

```js
let myArray = [];
let string = `Name :Hulk Color + Green Type Hero
Name :Venom Color :Black Type Anti Hero`;
// split by newline so we get the lines
let lines = string.split("\n");
// console.log(lines);
lines.forEach(transform);

function transform(line) {
  let obj = {};
  let parts = line.split(/Color|Type/);
  obj['name'] = parts[0].replace(/[^0-9a-z ]/gi, "").replace("Name", "").replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').trim();
  obj['color'] = parts[1].replace(/[^0-9a-z ]/gi, "").replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').trim();
  obj['type'] = parts[2].replace(/[^0-9a-z ]/gi, "").replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').trim();
  myArray.push(obj);
  // return obj;
}
// console.log(myArray);

// =============================== use array to split
let splitBy = ['name', 'color', 'type'];
let hero = 'Name :Hulk Color + Green Type Hero';

function heroToObj(hero, splitBy) {
  let obj = {};
  const regex = new RegExp(splitBy.join('|'), 'i');
  var parts = hero.split(regex);
  splitBy.forEach((key,index)=>obj[key] = parts[index+1].replace(/[^0-9a-z ]/gi, "").replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').trim() )
  return obj;
}
const heroObject = heroToObj(hero, splitBy);
console.log(heroObject);
```

=========================== another example ==================

```js
let hero = 'Name :Hulk\nColor + Green\nType Hero\nAnother text \nanother some texts';
let myArray = [];
// split by newline so we get the lines
let lines = hero.split("\n");
let obj = {};
let splitBy = ['name', 'color', 'type'];
lines.forEach(heroToObj);
function heroToObj(line) {
  splitBy.forEach((prop) => {
    var regEx = new RegExp(prop, "ig");
    // clean the line to account for  '+Name :Hulk\n Color + Green\n-Type Hero\nAnother text \another some texts'
    line = line.replace(/[^0-9a-z ]/gi, "").trim();
    if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith(prop.toLowerCase())) obj[prop] = line.replace(/[^0-9a-z ]/gi, "").replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').replace(regEx, '').trim()
  })
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: If you have only one line you can pass it to transform function directly: `transform("Name :Hulk Color + Green Type Hero");` and you can `return obj;` inside the function instead of adding to array `myArray.push(obj)`

Comment: you missed the "type" column that should be hero or anti hero

Comment: in my thought we can predefined an array of given key that we want something like ['name','color','type'] and then use that array to split the string

Comment: Updated with type, since this is OCR scan there can be many artifacts added and it's better to have a way to clean every part, in time you can observe potential problems and fix them

Comment: You can see my answer for updates, i've added a function that takes a line and an array and returns a object, array elements are used for split and object keys

Comment: what if we want to remove all remaining text for the last part, in my case it ended with \n, something like this let hero = 'Name :Hulk\nColor + Green\nType Hero\nAnother text \another some texts'. so after we expecting the type is all that comes before first \n

Comment: If you have the name, color or any other property you want to keep on different lines it's simple, just split by lines `\n` and check if the line contains the property you need. I'll  edit my answer and add an example how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example using [named capturing groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges#using_named_groups) and using the category/property names ['Name', 'Color', Type'] as delimeters within the string capturing all characters between those words into appropriately named groups [`(?<name>.*)`, `(?<color>.*)`, `(?<type>.*)`], and setting the `i` flag for case-insensitive matching.

```
const regex = /Name(?<name>.*)Color(?<color>.*)Type(?<type>.*)/i,
```

When calling [`exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) on this regular expression the named matches will be available within the `groups` property of the returned matches array.

From there you simply need to access each named group and clean its associated string, here using a regex to replace [non-word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet#character_classes) (`\W` which matches [^A-Za-z0-9_]) characters at either the beginning or end of the string.

```
const clean = (s) => s.replace(/^\W+|\W+$/, '');
```

Finally, combine them into a single object, here using a `for...of` loop to iterate the `Object.keys()` of the `groups` object, clean each matched string and assign it to the result object.

```js
const parse_ocr_string = (str) => {

  const clean = (s) => s.replace(/^\W+|\W+$/g, '');

  const regex = /Name(?<name>.*)Color(?<color>.*)Type(?<type>.*)/i;
  const { groups } = regex.exec(str);

  const result = {};
  for (const k of Object.keys(groups)) {
    result[k] = clean(groups[k]);
  }

  return result;
};

const s1 = 'Name :Hulk Color + Green Type Hero';
const s2 = 'Name :Venom Color :Black Type Anti Hero';

const obj1 = parse_ocr_string(s1);
const obj2 = parse_ocr_string(s2);

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
```

But you could also generalize this by accepting a `delimiters` parameter and passing `['String', 'key']` pairs to use in declaring a regex via the [`new RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp) constructor. You'll still need to adjust for other artifacts/case-sensitivity problems, but perhaps this gives you an idea of how you might proceed.

```js
const parse_ocr_string = (str, delimiters) => {

  const clean = (s) => s.replace(/^\W+|\W+$/g, '');

  const match_string = delimiters
    .map(([seq, key]) => `${seq}(?<${key}>.*)`)
    .join('');

  const regex = new RegExp(match_string, 'i');
  const { groups } = regex.exec(str);

  const result = {};
  for (const k of Object.keys(groups)) {
    result[k] = clean(groups[k]);
  }

  return result;
};

const s1 = 'Name :Hulk Color + Green Type =Hero';
// specify delimiters in some form, here tuples of ['Word', 'property']
const delimiters1 = [['Name', 'name'], ['Color', 'color'], ['Type', 'type']];

const obj1 = parse_ocr_string(s1, delimiters1);
console.log(obj1);

const s2 = 'AttaCk power: 24 Defense+ 90';
const delimiters2 = [['Attack Power', 'attack'], ['Defense', 'defense']];

const obj2 = parse_ocr_string(s2, delimiters2);
console.log(obj2);
```